# Equality of Series due to Rearrangements

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given $a_{n}\geq0$, let $b_{n}$ be rearrangement of $a_{n}$. Show that $\sum b_{n}=\sum a_{n}$

**My Proof** : Let $A_{n}=a_{0}+a_{1}+\cdots+a_{n}$ and let $B_{n}=b_{0}+b_{1}+\cdots+b_{n}$ be a rearrangements of $a_{n}$. Now we note that the sequence of the partial sums $A_{n}$ and $B_{n}$ are either finite, or either $A_{n}$ or $B_{n}$ approach infinity. Thus, it may either be the case that $A_{n}\leq\displaystyle\lim_{n\to+\infty}B_{n}$ or $B_{n}\leq\displaystyle\lim_{n\to+\infty}A_{n}$. We have that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to+\infty}B_{n}$ involves all the the sum over all $b_{n}$ and so it involves the sum over $a_{0},a_{1},...,a_{n}$ and same for $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to+\infty}A_{n}$ . Taking the limit $n\to+\infty$ we find that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to+\infty}B_{n}\leq \displaystyle\lim_{n\to+\infty}A_{n}$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to+\infty}A_{n}\leq\displaystyle\lim_{n\to+\infty}B_{n}$ and thus we have that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to+\infty}A_{n}=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to+\infty}B_{n}$

Is this a complete proof or is my proof missing some details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} a_n = \sup S$, where $S$ is the set of all partial sums of $(a_n)$.

Let $\sigma: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, the bijection, such that $b_n = a_{\sigma (n)}$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Now fix an arbitrary $m\in \mathbb{N}$. Then there exists a $M\in \mathbb{N}$, depending on $m$, such that $\{\sigma (1) , \sigma (2),\ldots , \sigma(m)\} \subseteq \{1,2, \ldots ,M\}$.
$\big($ for example if $b_1= a_1$ and $b_2=a_{100}$, then (for $M=100$), $\{\sigma(1), \sigma (2) \} = \{1, 100\} \subset \{1,2, \ldots ,100 \}$. In general, just consider $M=\max \{\sigma (1) , \sigma (2),\ldots , \sigma(m)\} \ \big)$

This means that $$\sum_{k=1}^{m}b_k = \sum_{k=1}^{m}a_{\sigma(k)} \overset{a_n \geq 0}{\leq} \sum_{k=1}^{M}a_{k} \leq \sup S = \sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} a_n$$

Thus $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$$

With the symmetric of this argument you have that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$$
and that completes the proof